# Currency symbols formatting

Tags: import, google-sheets-api, cell, currency, currency-formatting

How do I format cells in Google Sheets to show the currency symbol in the cell, but not to have the symbol when you double click the cell or go to the bar at the top that contains the data? - because I cannot then sum-up the values when there's a currency symbol from pasted data from invoices, and I want to import all my data to Gsheets to allow my bosses to access the sheets to avoid sending countless emails with reports done in Excel.

For example - in the Excel documents that I maintain at work, I paste data from invoices into the designated cells and they mainly contain EUR, GBP or USD currency symbols, but when I go to that cell and *activate* that cell,, either by double click or just when I click the cell and view that data in the top bar that contains it, the currency symbol is not shown, which allows me to do SUMS.

When I imported my reports to the Gsheets to migrate, when I pasted values from invoices which contain currency symbols, they stay shown in every way and I figured it out by tinkering with it, that when the currency symbol is shown/not shown as I mentioned above, I could either do or not do SUMS.